# Как стилизовать скроллбар?

Tags: html, css

Сколько не искал в интернете никак не могу найти подходящий метод кастомизации скроллбара наподобие того, что на картинке. Мне даже интересно, возможна ли такая кастомизация?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это фейковый скроллбар, сделанный собственноручно обычными  div...или на canvas...или с помощью svg. Он управляется через js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроссбраузерной кастомизации скроллбара средствами CSS до сих пор нет.

Обычно используют различные решения на JS/jQuery, например, [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar).

В браузерах семейства Webkit можно стилизовать следующими префиксными свойствами:

`::-webkit-scrollbar` - Скроллбар (1)
`::-webkit-scrollbar-button` - Кнопки на скроллбаре (2)
`::-webkit-scrollbar-track` - Трек (3)
`::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece` - Видимая часть трека (4)
`::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` - Ползунок (5)
`::-webkit-scrollbar-corner` - Уголок (6)
`::-webkit-resizer` - Край для изменения размера (7)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно об этом: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/polzovatelskie-skrollbary-v-webkit